# Bash script using sed to find a line WITH brackets

Tags: bash, sed

Good Morning,

Im writing a script to spool up a server.

What i need to do is find the line that has the following text

```
[curl]
```

and then directly on the next line, i need to insert

```
curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

What I have at the moment is as follows;

```
sudo sed '/[curl]/a curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini
```

But when i run it, it seems to insert the line on every second line, not just after the line that displays [curl]

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square braces are used to generate character classes. You need to escape them.

```
sed '/\[curl\]/a curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense ... thank you, that worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way

```
echo "curl.cainfo = ..." >> /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/override.ini
```

Because it is always a bad idea to change the provided php.ini ;)